# Lightweight doxygen html output

Tags: doxygen

Is there for doxygen is a more lightweight HTML backend, which does not fill the page with tons of divs and tables? When looking at the css file, the output seems quite bloated. It possible to write another backend. I ask if there already exists one.

Reasons why I need this

1. It makes it easier to integrate the dox with the rest of the website.
2. I use hyphenate.js to make my "Related Pages" look good. But that script needs to know which tags it should use. This is much easier with less bloat markup.
3. Doxygen lacks complete documentation on how the output markup making reverse engineering using Firefox Web Developer tool necessary to modify the 1k lines CSS file. Less bloat markup makes less need for documentation, and it makes documentation more easy for Dimitri to maintain.
4. Less bloat markup makes the pages more portable.

Comment: *Why* do you want a more lightweight HTML output?  I too would often like  a simpler form, but rarely does my aesthetic choice of code style have any real commercial justification :)  I presume your aim is to create user documentation for your code.  Quite seriously, it would be useful to know why you believe the HTML bloat is preventing that.

Comment: The "bloat" you speak of also makes the output infinitely more customizable. I for one am happy it's there, it saves me a lot of work. All I have to do is bang up a few CSS styles, not rewrite the entire generated output.

Comment: @CodyGray All I have to do now is to read through 1k lines to find the rule that I want to modify :-(. The most beautiful thing would be a fully customizable tag-map, where I can tell doxygen to wrap element X inside tag Y.

Comment: I use Chrome's inspector. Firefox and IE have similar features. I forgot how I ever did web design without them. Agreed about the tag map, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do really depends on exactly what you want to end up with.

There are 'Input Filters', eg: ftp://ftp.rsa.com/pub/dsg/public/doxygen/doxyfilt.pl and 'Output Filters, eg: http://www.bigsister.ch/doxygenfilter/doxygenfilter.html . Writing a customized Filter should do exactly what you want. Using existing Code and putting up with it's limitations will be faster and may provide ideas for writing your own Program (if you wish to do so).

You can try this Website http://www.dirtymarkup.com/ with the output that you object to and see if one of the Tools it suggests will "clean" the Code up enough to your liking without removing too much functionality (IE: the ability to click on Links and expand / contract Sections).

If you really want it 'raw' try HTML2Text https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text and then you can 'wrestle it back' with Text2HTML http://txt2html.sourceforge.net/ . That will strip it bare and yet give you back some minimal HTML functionality (preserve Linking).

There are MANY 'HTML <-> Text' converters, in many Languages, use a Search Engine to find your own Source; one that is most suitable for you.

Here is a List of Tools from a reputable Site: http://www.w3.org/Tools/html2things.html .

Here is an List of alternates to convert Languages to HTML: http://www.w3.org/Tools/Prog_lang_filters.html . More Info here: http://www.w3.org/Tools/Filters.html .

Answer (score 3):

With doxygen you can export your data in html format, tex format, XML (which you can later parse as you want), RTF, Man pages or Docbook.

The html output supports a custom header, footer and stylesheet (CSS) with the **HTML_STYLESHEET** attribute which might be what you want. You can rewrite those and adjust the output as you like.

If nothing satisfies you, then you might start thinking manually parsing one of the outputs above with your own scripting language and generate the desired format by yourself (if that suits you) or taking over control of the output generation directly via doxygen sources (https://github.com/doxygen/)

Sources: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html

Comment: The question is about existence of third-party add-ons. But your answer indicates that the answer is no. I have to implement the backend myself using the interface CodeOutputInterface.

Comment: In my experience there's no back-end to accomplish what you need because doxygen allows a certain level of flexibility in the output formatting. Edit: added the fallback solution: edit the sources by yourself.

Comment: I speak about the body markup. Because the interface has a huge number of entry points that has to be implemented, I asked if someone had done it before.